# SwiftUI @ObservedObject does not get updated on Async fetch of the image

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, combine

I have an app that fetches a list of items with images URL's from remote API, and then it has to fetch an image per item from given url inside that item's position. 
The problem is that when scrolling up and down and thus removing list items from view and moving them back into view they do show up. However on initial load they stay in "loading" status forever until moved out and in. 
My code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var artObjectStore: ArtObjectStore
    @State private var pageCount = 1
    @State private var tappedLink: String? = nil
    @Environment(\.imageCache) var cache: ImageCache

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {

                Section(header: Text("Art")) {

                    List {
                        ForEach(artObjectStore.artObjects, id: \.self) { artObject in
                            self.link(for: artObject)

                        }
                        Button(action: loadMore) {
                            Text("")
                        }
                        .onAppear {
                            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime(uptimeNanoseconds: 10)) {
                                self.loadMore()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Art objects")
        }
        .onAppear(perform: loadMore)

    }

    func loadMore() {
        pageCount += 1
        artObjectStore.loadMore(pageCount)
    }

    private func link(for artObject: ArtObject) -> some View {
        let selection = Binding(get: { self.tappedLink },
            set: {
                UIApplication.shared.endEditing()
                self.tappedLink = $0
        })

        return NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(artObject: artObject, cache: self.cache),
                              tag: artObject.id,
                              selection: selection) {
            HStack(alignment: .center) {
                VStack(alignment: .leading){
                    Text("\(artObject.title)").font(.system(size: 12))
                    Text("\(artObject.principalOrFirstMaker)").font(.system(size: 9)).foregroundColor(.gray)
                }
                Spacer()
                AsyncImage(
                    url: URL(string: artObject.headerImage.url)!,
                    cache: self.cache,
                    width: 200,
                    height: 50
                )
            }
        }
    }
}


extension UIApplication {
    func endEditing() {
        sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

**Image container:**

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine
import Foundation

class ImageLoader: ObservableObject {

    let objectWillChange = ObservableObjectPublisher()

    private var cancellable: AnyCancellable?
    @Published var image: UIImage? {
        willSet {
            objectWillChange.send()
        }
    }


    private let url: URL

    private var cache: ImageCache?

    init(url: URL, cache: ImageCache? = nil) {
        self.url = url
        self.cache = cache
    }

    deinit {
        cancellable?.cancel()
    }

    private func cache(_ image: UIImage?) {
        image.map { cache?[url] = $0 }
    }

    func load() {
        if let image = cache?[url] {
            self.image = image
            return
        }

        cancellable = URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
            .map { UIImage(data: $0.data) }
            .replaceError(with: nil)
            .handleEvents(receiveOutput: { [weak self] in self?.cache($0) })
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .assign(to: \.image, on: self)


    }

    func cancel() {
        cancellable?.cancel()
    }
}


struct AsyncImage: View {
    @ObservedObject private var loader: ImageLoader
    private let width: CGFloat?
    private let height: CGFloat?
    @State var spin = false

    init(url: URL, cache: ImageCache? = nil, width: CGFloat? = nil, height: CGFloat? = nil) {
        loader = ImageLoader(url: url, cache: cache)
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
    }

    var body: some View {
        image
            .onAppear(perform: loader.load)
            .onDisappear(perform: loader.cancel)
    }

    private var image: some View {
        Group {
            if loader.image != nil {
                Image(uiImage: loader.image!)
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .frame(width: width, height: height)
            } else {
                Image("loadingCircle")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                    .rotationEffect(.degrees(spin ? 360 : 0))
                    .animation(Animation.linear(duration: 0.8).repeatForever(autoreverses: false))
                    .onAppear() {
                        self.spin.toggle()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

protocol ImageCache {
    subscript(_ url: URL) -> UIImage? { get set }
}

struct TemporaryImageCache: ImageCache {
    private let cache = NSCache<NSURL, UIImage>()

    subscript(_ key: URL) -> UIImage? {
        get { cache.object(forKey: key as NSURL) }
        set { newValue == nil ? cache.removeObject(forKey: key as NSURL) : cache.setObject(newValue!, forKey: key as NSURL) }
    }
}


struct ImageCacheKey: EnvironmentKey {
    static let defaultValue: ImageCache = TemporaryImageCache()
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
    var imageCache: ImageCache {
        get { self[ImageCacheKey.self] }
        set { self[ImageCacheKey.self] = newValue }
    }
}
```

I did try to add willSet on the image, that doesn't seem to work. Can you help me?

Comment: Feels like an off main thread update. What happens when you call loadMore in ContentView without the DispatchAsync.

Comment: the loadMore doesn't have to do anything as it only loads other cells, the problem is the _ImageLoader.load()_

Answer (score 1):

All below tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4

Modified worked `AsyncImage`

I changed `Group` to `VStack` and it started updating

```
    private var image: some View {
        VStack {                        // << here !!
            if loader.image != nil {
```

Modified worked image loader

```
class ImageLoader: ObservableObject {

    @Published var image: UIImage?

    private var cancellable: AnyCancellable?
    private let url: URL
    private var cache: ImageCache?

    init(url: URL, cache: ImageCache? = nil) {
        self.url = url
        self.cache = cache
    }

    deinit {
        cancellable?.cancel()
    }

    private func cache(_ image: UIImage?) {
        self.image = image
        image.map { cache?[url] = $0 }
    }

    func load() {
        if let image = cache?[url] {
            self.image = image
            return
        }

        cancellable = URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
            .map { UIImage(data: $0.data) }
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .replaceError(with: nil)
            .sink(receiveValue: { [weak self] in self?.cache($0) })
    }

    func cancel() {
        cancellable?.cancel()
    }
}
```

Comment: the cache() function doesn't get triggered, I added a breakpoint there..

Comment: sorry, I didn't check it properly, it doesn't work :(

Comment: I do get a lot of HTTP load failed, 0/0 bytes (error code: -999 [1:89])

Comment: I was on iOS 13.2 though, updating now, maybe this helps

Comment: @Async-, just wanted to ask about if your urls are valid, because I tested just with found in google image that definitely exists.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212558/discussion-between-async-and-asperi).

Comment: whoever needs the fix for this, just add cancellable?.cancel() before calling another URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher.